# AForge , How can I set webcam framerate in ver 2.2.5

Tags: webcam, aforge

I'm working on the project that record the frame from dual webcam

Due to the dropping frame problem , I want to set webcam framerate to 15(default is

30).

But the DesiredFrameRate property is no longer in use in ver 2.2.5.

Does there exist any solutions to set the framerate ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no, it is no longer possible in 2.2.5. All media types are grouped by frame size and the final media type to use is matched based on the frame size only. Any input framerate you would have specified is discarded.

You have to use an older version or change the AForge code.